# Can I save user input to a plist that lives in the resources folder on iOS?

Tags: ios, persistence, plist

I have a plist in my Resources folder that I'm using to store conversion information.  I'd like to give the user the ability to "turn off" certain units so that those units will never be used in conversions.  I don't want to have to maintain two lists with the conversion information in it.

I am able to save data back to that plist file in the stimulator. (using writeToFile and the pathForResource).  I'm wondering if this is a problematic approach.

- Will there be an issues with this on deployment? (i.e. will Apple seal the plist)
- What will happen if I push out an upgrade? What if that upgrade contains new units added to the list?
- Would doing something like copying the plist to the user's documents directory make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to change the app bundle.  Further the app is signed.  Instead copy the plist to the documents directory on first start and access from there.

Comment: ok. that's what i suspected but couldn't get verification. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No whatever is in the application bundle is offlimit has the DRM on iPhone needs it to stay the same.
 You should save your preferences in the Apllication Document folder or Preference folder.

Answer (score 1):

Use an iOS [Settings Bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html)...

Comment: As I said, I don't want to duplicate the conversion information which I would have to do for the settings bundle. I also don't want to manually create 10-20 settings (which I'd have to do for the settings inside the app).